# PostgreSQL - column doesn't exist (WHERE with AS)

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, postgresql

i am a bit newbie to PostgreSQL, but i have a few experiences with MySQL.

The Postgres is showing me and error - COLUMN doesn't exist, but this is a "virtual column", created by AS.

Code, which is working very well in MySQL:

```
  SELECT place.*, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((place.lattitude - $1) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS($2 * pi() / 180) * COS(place.lattitude * pi() / 180) *POWER(SIN(($3 - place.longitude) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) )) AS "distance" FROM place WHERE place.longitude BETWEEN $4 AND $5 AND place.lattitude BETWEEN $6 AND $7 HAVING "distance" < $8 ORDER BY "distance" LIMIT 10
```

But Postgres is showing Column "distance" does not exist.

How can I rewrite it? (Please write full SQL query, not "*How to*")

*$number* is variable (against SQL injection)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT place.*, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((place.lattitude - $1) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS($2 * pi() / 180) * COS(place.lattitude * pi() / 180) *POWER(SIN(($3 - place.longitude) * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) )) AS "distance"
      FROM place
      WHERE place.longitude BETWEEN $4 AND $5 AND
            place.lattitude BETWEEN $6 AND $7
     ) p
WHERE "distance" < $8
ORDER BY "distance"
LIMIT 10;
```

You don't want to use a subquery in MySQL because it materializes the intermediate result.  Other databases are smarter in how they optimize queries, and do not necessarily materialize subqueries.